# Trying to run websocket server from my local PC

Tags: websocket, uwp

I am trying to develop a web-socket server app for my UWP Windows 10 App.

This is my code:

```
class Server
{
    public  async void Start()
    {
        MessageWebSocket webSock = new MessageWebSocket();

        //In this case we will be sending/receiving a string so we need to set the MessageType to Utf8.
        webSock.Control.MessageType = SocketMessageType.Utf8;

        //Add the MessageReceived event handler.
        webSock.MessageReceived += WebSock_MessageReceived;

        //Add the Closed event handler.
        webSock.Closed += WebSock_Closed;

        Uri serverUri = new Uri("ws://127.0.0.1/motion");

        try
        {
            //Connect to the server.
            await webSock.ConnectAsync(serverUri);

            //Send a message to the server.
            await WebSock_SendMessage(webSock, "Hello, world!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Add code here to handle any exceptions
        }

    }

    //The MessageReceived event handler.
    private void WebSock_MessageReceived(MessageWebSocket sender, MessageWebSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        DataReader messageReader = args.GetDataReader();
        messageReader.UnicodeEncoding = Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8;
        string messageString = messageReader.ReadString(messageReader.UnconsumedBufferLength);

        //Add code here to do something with the string that is received.
    }


    //The Closed event handler
    private void WebSock_Closed(IWebSocket sender, WebSocketClosedEventArgs args)
    {
        //Add code here to do something when the connection is closed locally or by the server
    }

    //Send a message to the server.
    private async Task WebSock_SendMessage(MessageWebSocket webSock, string message)
    {
        DataWriter messageWriter = new DataWriter(webSock.OutputStream);
        messageWriter.WriteString(message);
        await messageWriter.StoreAsync();
    }
}
```

It errors here: 
 **await webSock.ConnectAsync(serverUri);**

with this error:

**Not found (404). (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80190194)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any personal experience with it, but you might want to give [IotWeb HTTP Server](http://sensaura.org/pages/tools/iotweb/) a try. It seems to be a portable embedded HTTP and web socket server that also supports UWP and can be run inside Windows Store and Windows 10 IoT Core applications.

Judging from its [repository](https://github.com/sensaura-public/iotweb), it's rather new and not exactly mature, nor does it have a lot of documentations or samples available. There's a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IotWeb) available, though.

Unfortunately I didn't manage to find any other alternative yet.

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
await webSock.ConnectAsync(serverUri);
```

Is try to connect to existing server at ws://127.0.0.1/motion, Not to deploy a server on this address.

You can look for ways to build a c# WebSocket server at the follwing links:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_server
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/57060/Web-Socket-Server

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am looking to host a web-socket server from my local workstation PC. Will those links give me that?

Comment: using UWP and not normal desktop

Comment: You can use SignalR for WS

Comment: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/deployment/tutorial-signalr-self-host - How to Self-Host a SignalR without IIS

Comment: I appreciate you trying to help me but you are missing the point :) I want to serve web sockets on a NON server OS PC.  Also, I would not want to use SignalR because I prefer to deal with binary data and not Base64 string

Comment: At the button line since WB is based on TCP protocol, you need to open a TCP server on your "non server PC". You can build the WS TCP server by yourself like this project: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/57060/Web-Socket-Server or to use SingalR hosted without IIS.

Comment: hi, thanks again for your time.  That was what I thought but as the error line I depicted it did not work. I shall look at that link and see how they make it work. thank you